# How can I identify specific numbers in string, and create and populate another span with this number?

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a span where the value possibilities are: "Showing 1 item" or "Showing x to y of z items". Z can be any positive number.

```
<div class="result-container">
    <span id="results-label">Showing 1 to 10 of 33 items</span>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to identify z and place it into a newly created span above this, using jQuery. Please note that "item(s)" is not static due to translations. Desired output:

```
<div class="result-container">
    <span id="total-results">33</span>
    <span id="results-label">Showing 1 to 10 of 33 items</span>
</div>
```

The regex I am using is \d+(?=[A-Za-z\s]*$) which seems to work
https://rubular.com/r/KrHmLUzEsWGU3P

I have two issues:

1. For some reason creating and inserting a new span fails:

https://jsfiddle.net/ubte7jx3/

2. I am unsure how to insert the regex result into the span afterwards.

Comment: How are you populating the `results-label` span?

Comment: I get a completed html output that I can add Javascript and css to.

Comment: What have you tried?  Which parts are you having difficulty with?  Getting the text?  Extracting the number?  Either via substr/substring or a regex?   Converting a string to a number?  Inserting new html?  Or are you hoping someone will just provide a solution for you?

Comment: Please see [ask]. You should show some code.

Comment: My apologies - I have added details and a jsfiddle.

Comment: Your fiddle had a function that wasn't called and was missing jquery (always check the browser console for errors).  Fixed that part: https://jsfiddle.net/ctzsn2oj/ with just config of the fiddle and removed wrapped function (so otherwise worked fine)

Comment: You can use "matching groups" in the regex, here's an old question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m, that was very helpful. Eventually I managed to make it work:
https://jsfiddle.net/r4fd9xcp/5/

Beginner's luck :)

Comment: Some subtle changes, and just FYI, here's what I'd probably do: https://jsfiddle.net/9np32efk/  eg use `.text()` instead of innerHTML just in-case there are some extra tags in the result label and a more explicit regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help in the comments I managed to arrive to a solution:

```
<div class="job-tile-result-container">
    <span id="tile-search-results-label">Showing 1 to 10 of 33 items</span>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".job-tile-result-container").prepend('<span id="total-results"></span>');
    var z_string = document.getElementById("tile-search-results-label").innerHTML;
    var z_results = z_string.match(/\d+(?=[A-Za-z\s]*$)/);
    console.log (z_results);
    document.getElementById("total-results").innerHTML = (z_results);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r4fd9xcp/5/